# Idiomatic clojure and Javascript expression for filtering a sequence based on the previous value

Tags: javascript, clojure

So I have a seq of integers. I'd like to pick every other element but only if the element preceding it is positive. For instance, given this input:

```
4, 9, -1, 8, 3, 20, -1, 7
```

I want to get this output:

```
9, 20
```

(Context: these values represent segments of text where a certain style has been applied. The 4, 9 pair indicates the user selected characters 4, 9 (exclusive) and clicked on "Bold". When the user "Unblods" only the first member of each pair becomes -1. So in order to find all "active"  styles I need to filter those with -1 out)

I am looking for both a Javascript and a Clojure solution (as this code needs to run both in the browser side and the server side).

Here's a possible JS impl.:

```
styleList.map(function(curr, i) {
  if (i % 2 == 1) 
    return (styleList[i - 1] >= 0) ? curr : -1;
  else
    return -1;
}).filter(function(curr) { return curr >= 0 })
```

I don't like this solution: the function that I pass to `.map()` uses the index `i` to inspect the previous value. This feels awkward. I am looking for a solution which is more functional.

**Edit**

Here's another solution which I don't like (again: not very functional due to the mutations to the `arr` object):

```
var arr = [];
styleList.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  arr.push(prev == -1 ? -1 : curr);
  return curr;
});
arr.filter(function(curr, i) {
  return i % 2 == 1 && curr >= 0;
});
```

**Edit 2**

Here's what @CandiedOrange has suggested (JS impl. using the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library):

```
_.zip(styleList, styleList.slice(1)).
  slice(0, -1).
  filter(function(pair, i) { return i % 2 == 0 }).
  filter(function(pair) { return pair[0] >= 0 }).
  map(function(pair) { return pair[1] })
```

comments:

- this can be shortened a bit by combining the two `.filter` calls. Still, I think it is better to keep them separated as the `i % 2 == 0` is an artifact of the impl. whereas the `pair[0] >= 0` is the "real business logic" needed here.
- this looks a bit verbose. I would have liked functional programming to handle such a task better. Is there any better solution in Clojure-land?

**Edit 3**

What's bothering me here, is the non functional (imperative) solution is quite trivial:

```
var result = [];
styleList.forEach(function(curr, i) {
  if (i % 2 == 1 && styleList[i - 1] >= 0)
    result.push(curr);
});
```

Sure it's not as terse as the Clojure solution but relies on fewer constructs so a JS developer is more likely to arrive at this than a Clojure developer is likely to arrive at the Clojure solution (which requires acquaintance with `->>` `partition` `first` `second` `map` and `filter`)

Comment: Well as long as you're taking the ints one at a time you're required to remember state.  Why not take them in pairs?  A function that takes x, y and a list.  Append y to list when x > 0.

Comment: @CandiedOrange what function/method would give me two consecutive pairs?

Comment: Convert your list to a list of pairs so  4, 9, -1, 8, 3, 20, -1 7 becomes [4, 9], [-1, 8], [3, 20], [-1, 7].  Then filter pairs based on sign [4, 9],  [3, 20]. Then map remaining pairs to a list of y values.  9, 20

Comment: Re edit 3. That actually is slightly functional.  The advantage of going more completely functional is that it allows a greater separation of concerns.  Suppose you had to validate that the list length is a multiple of 2.  Where are you going to put that code?  Every time you have to poke new code into an old working function you have to test it again for everything that calls it.  This is why Functions that do only one thing and do it well are cool.  Write them so they can stay closed and reuse them.

Comment: @ItayMaman So what "Idiomatic clojure and Javascript expressions" did you end up with? Used any answers that were given or created something else?

Answer (score 9):

In Clojure:

```
(->> your-list 
     (partition 2)
     (filter #(pos? (first %)))
     (map second))
```

Edit: explanation as requested by @CandiedOrange:

- Partition your-list into pairs
- Filter the pairs keeping only the ones where the first element is positive
- Transform each pair into a single item (the second)

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  How about some explanation?

Comment: @CandiedOrange translated the Clojure into plain English, does it make sense now?

Comment: Better, and a little familiar.  : )

Comment: @CandiedOrange I saw your above comment after I'd written my code. It's the most obvious solution, isn't it?

Comment: The other nice benefit is that solution is portable to clojurescript. You could use cljx and just have one code file for both

Comment: @DiegoBasch in a functional context yes it is.  Not that there would be any problem with using a comment to inspire an answer.  Just teasing you a bit since you implied my request was made due to a lack of understanding on my part when in fact it's due to stackoverflow psychologically conditioning me to be a knee jerk policy enforcer.  As if that makes me look any better...

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution

```
var array=[4, 9, -1, 8, 3, 20, -17];
var s;

for(var i=0; i < array.length ; i+=2) {

  if(array[i] < 0 || array[i+1]<0){ 
    continue;
  } else {
    if(!s) {
      s=array[i+1];  
    } else {    
      s=s+","+array[i+1];  
    }   
  }
}

alert(s);
```

Comment: Isn't this more procedural than functional?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this for the Javascript solution. It appears to address the dislikes that you have aired regarding a Javascript solution.

```js
function checkObjectCoercible(inputArg) {
    var type = typeof inputArg;

    if (type === 'undefined' || inputArg === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert argument to object');
    }

    return inputArg;
}

Object.defineProperty(Number, 'isPositive', {
    value: function (value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            return false;
        }

        return value === 0 ? (1 / value) === Infinity : value > 0;
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'groupsOf', {
    value: function (num) {
        var object = Object(checkObjectCoercible(this)),
            length = object.length,
            count = num >>> 0,
            newList = [],
            index,
            group,
            idx;

        if (length && count) {
            for (idx = 0; idx < length; idx += count) {
                group = [];
                group.length = count;
                for (index = 0; index < count; index += 1) {
                    group[index] = object[idx + index];
                }

                newList.push(group);
            }
        }

        return newList;
    }
});

var styleList = [4, 9, -1, 8, 3, 20, -1, 7],
    out = styleList.groupsOf(2).filter(function (pair) {
        return Number.isPositive(pair[0]) && typeof pair[1] === 'number';
    }).map(function (pair) {
        return pair[1];
    });

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(out, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

These solutions take into consideration the possible use of sparse arrays and `-0`. They also handle the condition where there may be an odd number of elements.

A further possibility.

```js
function checkObjectCoercible(inputArg) {
    var type = typeof inputArg;

    if (type === 'undefined' || inputArg === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert argument to object');
    }

    return inputArg;
}

Object.defineProperty(Number, 'isPositive', {
    value: function (value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            return false;
        }

        if (value === 0) {
            return (1 / value) === Infinity;
        }
        
        return value > 0;
    }
});

function pairByIndex(acc, item, index) {
    var key = Math.floor(index / 2);

    if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = [item];
        acc[key].length = 2;
    } else {
        acc[key][1] = item;
    }

    return acc;
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'toPairs', {
    value: function () {
        return checkObjectCoercible(this).reduce(pairByIndex, []);
    }
});

function firstEntry(pair) {
    return pair[0];
}

function secondEntry(pair) {
    return pair[1];
}

function firstEntryIsPositive(pair) {
    return Number.isPositive(firstEntry(pair));
}

var styleList = [4, 9, -1, 8, 3, 20, -1, 7],
    out = styleList.toPairs().filter(firstEntryIsPositive).map(secondEntry);

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(out, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var styleList = [4, 9, -1, 8, 3, 20, -1, 7];
var pairs = _.zip(_.filter(styleList, function(val, idx) { return idx % 2 == 0; }), 
                  _.filter(styleList, function(val, idx) { return idx % 2 == 1; }));

_.chain(pairs)
.filter(function (pair) { return pair[0] >= 0; })
.map(function (pair) { return pair[1]; })
.value();
```

`pairs` contains only the pairs you are interested in: `[[4,9],[-1,8],[3,20],[-1,7]]`. The [`chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) function is similar to the `->` threading macro in Clojure. The `filter` is keeping the pairs where the first element is greater or equal to zero. And the `map` is returning the second element of the pair. [`value`](http://underscorejs.org/#value) extracts the value of the `chain`.

[Michael Fogus](http://blog.fogus.me/) has a great book about functional JavaScript: [Functional JavaScript: Introducing Functional Programming with Underscore.js](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449360726)